# Adding alpha channel to RGB array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image array in RGB space and want to add the alpha channel to be all zeros. Specifically, I have a `numpy` array with shape (205, 54, 3) and I want to change the shape to (205, 54, 4) with the additional spot in the third dimension being all 0.0's. Which numpy operation would achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want an array with rgb values and make the rgb values look like `(205, 54, 4, 0)`? Please post an example of how the output should be.

Comment: @Linus OP means the input is a 3D array of dimensions 205 x 54 x 3.

Comment: @kennytm Correct - the input has shape (205, 54, 3) and I want it to have a shape of (205, 54, 4). As an example, `x.shape = (205,54,3)` and `x[0][0] = [255, 255, 255]` and I want `x[0][0] = [255, 255, 255, 0]`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use one of the stack functions ([stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)/[hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)/[vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)/[dstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)/[concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)) to join multiple arrays together.

```
numpy.dstack( ( your_input_array, numpy.zeros((205, 54)) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried a few of them, but couldn't seem to find the right one. `np.dstack` makes sense.

Comment: @kennytm for some reasons I cant understand in my case : data = np.dstack(( data, np.zeros((data[:,:,0].shape))))  return an array of type = float64 instead of uint8. Any clue ?

Comment: @pippo1980 specify the `dtype` in `np.zeros`. its default value is `float64`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Comment: Yep thanks I figured out. Didn’t want to edit your answer. Even if I am stuck in the no more question ban !! And don’t know how to recover

Answer (score 10):

If you have your current image as rgb variable then just use:

```
rgba = numpy.concatenate((rgb, numpy.zeros((205, 54, 1))), axis=2)
```

Concatenate function merge rgb and zeros array together. Zeros function creates array of zeros. We set axis to 2 what means we merge in the thirde dimensions. Note: axis are counted from 0.

Answer (score 10):

np array style, stack on depth dimension(channel dimension, 3rd dimension):

```
rgba = np.dstack((rgb, np.zeros(rgb.shape[:-1])))
```

but you should use OpenCV function:

```
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
```

Answer (score 5):

not sure if your still looking for an answer.

recently i am looking to achieve the exact same thing you are looking to do with numpy because i needed to force a 24 bit depth png into a 32. I agree that it makes sense to use dstack, but i couldnt get it to work. i used insert instead and it seems to achieved my goal.

```
# for your code it would look like the following:
rgba = numpy.insert(
    rgb,
    3, #position in the pixel value [ r, g, b, a <-index [3]  ]
    255, # or 1 if you're going for a float data type as you want the alpha to be fully white otherwise the entire image will be transparent.
    axis=2, #this is the depth where you are inserting this alpha channel into
)
```

hope this helps, good luck.